# Sorting items in a listview alphabetcally,price rating

Tags: android, sorting, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

my apllication has a listview that contains:
1.Title
2.Image
3.Rating
4.Price

Now i want to implement sorting in my listview ie through a dropdown box or spinner so that i can sort the items alphabetically,rating etc

Please provide me with some code.....

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check for the options selected into the spinner and based on that,you will have to send your sorted data to the listview(if you are using CursorAdapter,then everytime cursor should be fetch in sorting order you want your items to be in) for each of your option.

reloading the listview is the only solution to your problem,AFAIK.

Comment: actually iam extending the base adapter class  to display the list and i want to implement sorting in base adapter....kindly provide me with some sample code

Comment: provide your code...let me see what you have done till now.I can suggest changes then!

Comment: @user1034991: click on edit at end of your question. it will let you edit your question. In that window,you will see icons on top of window.you would find icon for "Code Sample" there.clicking on that would let you add code snippet to your question.